# google test/mock vs boost vs catch support for c++14/c++17

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, frameworks, tdd

I am evaluating which testing framework would be ideal for me.
The choice is among these three: `google test`, `boost.test` and `catch`.

I would like something robust that has not so many dependencies and that is able to support C++14/C++17 if needed.

Another question, do you know which framework big companies in the avionics/space fields use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like something robust that has not so many dependencies and that is able to support c++14/c++17 if needed.

[Google C++ test framework](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/README.md) requirements mention:

> A C++98-standard-compliant compiler

It works just fine with C++14, I personally use it. From the linked documentation you can see that it has no dependencies on external libraries (see section *requirements*).

[Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/limitations.md) known limitations mention:

> our desire to support C++98 compilers

It works just fine with C++14, I personally used it in a couple of projects at work. Catch is a header only library, it has no dependencies at all.

Boost C++ libraries usually perform compile-time detection of compiler support for the standards and features are enabled/disabled depending on the result.
As a rule of thumb, those libraries usually depend on some other libraries picked up from Boost itself.

> do you know which framework big companies in the avionics/space fields use?

Often they require not only to write tests but also to have a code coverage estimation. There are a plenty of professional tools for that, few of them are for free and (at least, as long as I know) there doesn't exist a standard de facto for that.

Comment: thank you very much for you reply. In your opinion is gtest the best one?

Comment: @user3770392 _The best one_ doesn't exist. That's the one that fits my requirements and my idea of test framework. Give them a try and choose **your** _best one_. ;-)

Comment: good point ;) I already decided to try all of them, but just wanted some other opinions ehehe

Comment: @user3770392 Then yes, gtest is the one that I prefer actually.